# Notation for Functional Iteration

Tags: notation, function-and-relation-composition

In my research, I often use functional iteration, and I usually denote
$$(f\circ f\circ f\circ\dots\circ f)(x)$$
by writing
$$f^n(x)$$
where $f$ was composed with itself $n$ times. However, this notation can be confusing at times, especially when dealing with the trigonometric functions. Does anyone know of any elegant ways of expressing iterated function composition that do not conflict with preexisting notations?

Comment: To future authors reading this question: Please use $(\sin x)^2$ and $(\log x)^2$ instead of $\sin^2 x$ and $\log^2 x$. The latter notation is ambiguous. The former is not.

Comment: @user76284 I dunno, I think it’s not a bad idea to write $\sin^2 x$ because authors almost always mean $(\sin x)^2$ and almost never $\sin\sin x$. Also, $\sin^2 x$ avoids those ugly parentheses that go around $(\sin x)^2$.

Comment: The problem is that $f^n$ normally denotes $f$ composed $n$ times. The "special notation" for trigonometric and logarithmic functions conflicts with that. You can see the conflict at play with $\sin^{-1} x$. Does it denote $\arcsin x$, or $(\sin x)^{-1}$? Why is the power of 2 a special case?

Comment: $\sin \sin x$ isn't common, but in number theory you do frequently see terms like $\log \log \log x$, which can be written more concisely as $\log^3 x$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition):

> To avoid ambiguity, some mathematicians choose to write $f^{\circ n}$ for the $n$-th iterate of the function $f$.

Comment: And this convention makes sense in general. E.g. $A^n = ∏_{i < n} A$ but $A^{\oplus n} = \bigoplus_{i < n} A$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* The paper *[Notations for Iteration of Functions, Iteral](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0152)* by Valerii Salov might be interesting. He proposes a new notation and gives in section 3 a short survey  about existing notation.

> He refers in this section besides some others to
>
> - *[Iterative Functional Equations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CEKKFZ8)* by M. Kuczma, B. Choczewski, R. Ger stating that *composition* $\circ$ of functions is the only inner operation which be defined in the family $\mathcal{F}(x)$ of self-mappings for a set $X$. The system $(\mathcal{F}(X),\circ)$ is with $\mathrm{id}_X$ a non-commutative monoid with iterates defined as the powers of $n$ of an element $f\in\mathcal{F}(X)$, where $n$ is a non-negative integer:
>     \begin{align*}
>   n\in\mathbb{N},f^0=\mathrm{id}_X,f^{n+1}=f\circ f^n
>   \end{align*}
>
> another notation was introduced by D. Knuth in
>
> - *[The Art of Computer Programming, Vol. 2 Seminumerical algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01AY4ZHKE)*. There he chooses square parentheses to reduce ambiguity with powers of multiplication.
>     \begin{align*}
>   f^{[n]}(x)=f(f^{[n-1]}(x))
>   \end{align*}